# Rearranging Rows To Columns using sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

i am transferring data from old database to new database. In old database the format lok like this

[image: enter code here]

i need change this into like this

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to solve this ....,

Comment: is the combination of barcode and process unique across all rows?

Comment: maybe [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will give you a hint..

Comment: @Nico can you explain in brief

Comment: Can the order of `Process` change? If not then that should be the header of the column, and pivot the volume values.

Comment: @Segfault yes they are unique as per above

Comment: I'd ***strongly*** advise against your new data design as it has repeating fields/columns and thus is a violation of First Normal Form and a really awful approach for SQL and Relational databases.  Your current design may not be ideal, but if you have to distinguish your new columns with *numbers* instead of distinct names, then you are likely on the wrong path.

Comment: A better approach would be to have new columns named `PUCVolume, BCVolume, FPCVolume`.  This would also be easier to convert too and a whole lot easier to use once converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do this with a Pivot statement, as the comments imply, but to my mind it is more straight forward to use joins.  Join the same table to itself twice, then you will have the table in the result set to select from three times.  If your Processes are consistently these three then I recommend this:

```
SELECT a.barcode, a.process as First, a.volume as FirstVolume,
       b.process as Second, b.volume as Second Volume,
       c.process as Third, c.volume as ThirdVolume
FROM Volumes a
LEFT JOIN Volumes b on b.barcode = a.barcode and b.process = 'BC'
LEFT JOIN Volumes c on c.barcode = a.barcode and c.process = 'FPC'
WHERE a.process = 'PUC';
```

This makes assumes there is always a PUC process...

If you don't know what values might be in the process column, we can do it like this:

```
SELECT a.barcode, a.process as First, a.volume as FirstVolume,
       b.process as Second, b.volume as Second Volume,
       c.process as Third, c.volume as ThirdVolume
FROM Volumes a
LEFT JOIN Volumes b on b.barcode = a.barcode and b.process <> a.process
LEFT JOIN Volumes c on c.barcode = a.barcode and c.process <> a.process and c.process <> b.process;
```

This doesn't make any guarantees that the first process column is the same on each row though, only that you get the three different processes for each barcode on each row.